# WPF Reuseble Style.Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How can i reuse following trigger? I need to reuse this to all the clear buttons in the window. button will only visible when selecting a item in the listview. So i need to pass the `Binding ElementName=teachers` as parameter. Is there any way to do this?

```
<Button Width="15"  Grid.Column="1" Content="X" Margin="0,2,5,2" Command="{Binding ClearSubjectCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=teachers, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

---

***EDIT***

Tried attached property. but no success.

```
<Button Width="15"  Grid.Column="1" Content="X" Margin="0,2,5,2" Command="{Binding ClearSubjectCommand}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        local:ThemeProperties.BindingElementName="teachers" Style="{StaticResource cancelButton}"/>
```

and style,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="cancelButton">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  ElementName= local:ThemeProperties.BindingElementName, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

class,

```
public static class ThemeProperties
{
    public static string GetBindingElementName(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(BindingElementNameProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBindingElementName(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BindingElementNameProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BindingElementName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingElementNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindingElementName", typeof(string), typeof(ThemeProperties), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("teachers"));
}
```

Comment: Really don't know answer, but I probably would solve this differently. I would determine whether buttons should be visible in ViewModel and then I would use some BoolToVisibility Convertor

Comment: above code is perfectly working. `teachers` is a list view and button only visible when item is selected otherwise it is collapsed. only thing i want to do is parameterize the listview name. so then i can use it in everywhere i want.

Comment: If i can pass a parameter to the style would be perfectly fine. then i can pass the listview name to the style

Comment: give me some time please. I am working on that :)

Comment: @ViktorLaCroix: sure waiting for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about declaring style as a `Resource` and re-use it using `StaticResource` markup extension something like this -

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Style>
      <Style x:Key="CommonButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
          <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=teachers,
                                       Path=SelectedItem}" 
                           Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
              </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And use it for different buttons -

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Style="{StaticResource CommonButtonStyle}"/>
<Button x:Name="Button2" Style="{StaticResource CommonButtonStyle}"/>
<Button x:Name="Button3" Style="{StaticResource CommonButtonStyle}"/>
```

**UPDATE**

In case `ListView` lies somewhere in the Visual Tree of `Button`, you can use the `RelativeSource` in the style instead of using the `ElementName` in binding something like this -

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                        FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" 
                           Value="{x:Null}">
```

But in case they are not related, you need to use `attached property` to pass parameter to styles. This link [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/10/01/wpf-creating-parameterized-styles-with-attached-properties/) might get you started.

**UPDATE 2**

I have got it working with attached property but modifying bit of your code. Here it is -

```
public static class ThemeProperties
{
    public static object GetSelectedValue(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(SelectedValueProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedValue(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedValue", typeof(object), 
          typeof(ThemeProperties), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, 
           FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));     
}
```

*XAML* -

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="cancelButton">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="local:ThemeProperties.SelectedValue"
                         Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Here goes your ListView and button -

```
   <StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="lstView" ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30"  Width="100"
                local:ThemeProperties.SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem,
                            ElementName=lstView}"
                Style="{StaticResource cancelButton}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: `teachers` is a list view and button only visible when item is selected otherwise it is collapsed. only thing i want to do is parameterize the listview name. so then i can use it in everywhere i want.

Comment: Oh you means that different buttons depends on listview other than `teachers` Right?

Comment: Did `ListView` lies in the Visual tree of the button anywhere? How are they related to each other?

Comment: here is the visual tree
`<TabItem><Grid><Grid><Button/></Grid><ListView/></Grid></TabItem>` If i can pass a parameter to the style would be perfectly fine. then i can pass the listview name to the style

Comment: Since `ListView` does not belong to button as an ancestor, `RelativeSource` can't be used. Try looking at the link i posted at last in my updated answer. It might help you out.

Comment: any idea about binding the attached property. i tried following, its not working for me. `Binding="{Binding  ElementName=local:ThemeProperties.BindingElementName, Path=SelectedItem}"`

Comment: You need to use paranthesis in binding for attached properties - `Binding="{Binding ElementName=(local:ThemeProperties.BindingElementName), Path=SelectedItem}"`

Comment: You get the concept right of attached property but the usage is not correct. I have updated the answer, have a look. Working for me with a sample i tried.

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry it took me so long. But finally I got it. I used custom converter and I know it's not exactly what you wanted, but it works just fine. And it provides functionality you wanted.

First of all here is my *SelectionToVisibilityConverter*

```
public class SelectionToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is my view:

```xml
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Test:SelectionToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,29,0,0" Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=TestItemsSelectedItem}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <ListView Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,29,0,0" Name="listView2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TestItems2}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=TestItems2SelectedItem}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding Path=ReloadCommand}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=listView1, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,135,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding Path=ReloadCommand}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=listView2, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,135,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
</Grid>
```

Please ignore SelectedItem on ListViews and ReloadCommand on buttons. I used it to test this. Everytime selected item of some ListView is changed visibility of corresponding button is re-evaluated.

**EDIT**

My last idea is to crate custom control and define style/template for this control. Something like this:

```
    <Style x:Key="CustomControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Test:MyFirstCustomControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Test:MyFirstCustomControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ListView Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5, 5, 0, 0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
                        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,110,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="button1" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This way that trigger would be shared among all your MyFirstConstomControl where you set

```xml
Style="{StaticResource CustomControlStyle}"
```

I don't think it's easy, but I don't know any better, so I just bring what I got.

Comment: To hide the button this is quite OK. but what about if i need to change some more values based on the selection. lets say i have a save button as well and i need to change the button text based on the selection. so style is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal please let me drink my coffee and I will try it again.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal I am sorry... I really don't see myself succeeding. I give up, but you could try create custom control then define controltemplate and in that template provide your trigger. I look at edit of my answer